# What's the functionality of a class has a static member of it self?

Tags: c#, c++, static-members

An example:

```
class E
{
    public static E e;
    //...
};
```

What's the functionality of this or under which circumstances should we use this? Thanks.

Comment: It could be anything. Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Might be used for singleton.

Comment: Or maybe some kind of prototype object.

Comment: Since it has semi-colon at end, I presume it is C++ question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Its valid only till the point `e` is not accessed. Otherwise everything get compiled and is running.

Comment: The answers for C++ and C# might be different. Which one are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

One of usages can be to implement singleton (When you need a class that has only one instance, and you need to provide a global point of access to the instance): [Implementing Signleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

```
public class Singleton
{
  private static Singleton instance;

  private Singleton() {}

 public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ultimate link for singletons in C#: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A `static` variable cannot hold a reference to anything else that is declared in an instance, but rather a static variable/method belongs to the *type* instead of an *instance of a type*.

Consider this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static string _testStaticString;
    private string _testInstanceString;

    public void TestClass()
    {
        _testStaticString = "Test"; //Works just fine
        _testInstanceString = "Test";

        TestStatic();
    }

    private static void TestStatic()
    {
        _testInstanceString = "This will not work"; //Will not work because the method is static and belonging to the type it cannot reference a string belonging to an instance.
        _testStaticString = "This will work"; //Will work because both the method and the string are static and belong to the type.
    }
}
```

The many usages are so many it could fill books. As someone mentioned, the Singleton pattern makes use of it.